# Active record attributes and type conversion in Ruby/ rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an attribue `attempts` in database of `integer` type (initial value is 0 )

When I do `@user.attempts += 1` , it throws `TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String`

So, I conclude that rails does not convert attributes automatically according to their datatype.

When I do

```
@user.attempts.to_i +=1
```

it throws `NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_i=' for "0":String`

and when I do,

```
@user.attempts.to_i = @user.attempts.to_i + 1
```

it throws `NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_i=' for "0":String` again.

And this,

```
@user.attempts = @user.attempts.to_i + 1
```

works fine.

I think the reason is that when I do `@user.attempts.to_i + 1` , it actually changes the `@user.attempts` on left side .

Can somebody throw some light on this behavior ?

**EDIT**

*Migration*

```
    class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :users do |t|
          t.string :email 
          t.string :email_pass 
          t.integer :attempts 
          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

*Create table script*

```
-- Table: users

-- DROP TABLE users;

CREATE TABLE users
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  email character varying(255), 
  email_pass character varying(255), 
  attempts character varying(255),
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE users
  OWNER TO jashwant;
```

I see that in db `attempts` is character type.

So, what should be the proper way to alter its datatype.
And I also stand out for my first question, whats the reason for that type conversion ?

Comment: Show your migration script, and also a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `+=` like this :

```
something += 1
```

it is the same as :

```
something = something + 1
```

And when you do,

```
obj.method = val
```

it is the same as :

```
obj.method=(val)
```

So you are actually calling `#to_i=` on `@user.attempts` which does not exist.

When you do `@user.attempts = @user.attempts.to_i + 1`, your call is the same as this one :

```
@user.attempts=(@user.attempts.to_i + 1)
```

which exists and so works fine.

Comment: Better explanation would be with send: `obj.method = val` is the same as `obj.send('method=',val)`, So `@user.attempts.to_i += 1` is the same as `@user.attempts.send('to_i=', @user.attempts.to_i + 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use change_column in a migration:

```
rails g migration change_attempts_to_integer_for_users
```

...

Open and edit the migration

```
def self.up
  change_column(:users, :attempts, :integer)
end

def self.down
  change_column(:users, :attempts, :text)
end
```

Run the migration.